# git clean -dfx does not remove ignored directory

Tags: git

I use git 1.7.9.5 and I have a directory `_hashdist` with no tracked files in it. This is my `.gitignore`:

```
*~
*.pyc
*.pyo

/opt
/bld
/db
/src
/_hashdist
/local
```

so it is ignored, as shown by:

```
$ git status --ignored
# On branch master
# Ignored files:
#   (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   _hashdist/
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Then I would like to delete it by:

```
$ git clean -dfx
Removing _hashdist/
```

It correctly says that it is removing it. But nothing actually happens:

```
$ git status --ignored
# On branch master
# Ignored files:
#   (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   _hashdist/
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

or

```
$ ls -d _hashdist/
_hashdist/
```

the directory is still there. This has been very perplexing to me, as I have always used `git clean -dfx` to clean everything, and this is the first time that it doesn't work.

Comment: yes, git should delete that directory, but obviously was not able to do so. Does manually deleting with `rm -rf _hashdist` work?

Comment: Yes, manually deleting the directory works fine (that's what I've been doing in this case, it's just annoying).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use strace to find out, what is going on.

You should see something like:

```
$ strace git clean -dfx
[...]
unlink("_hashdist/foo")                 = 0
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
rmdir("_hashdist/")                     = 0
[...]
```

There is the `unlink` call to delete the file and the `rmdir` call to delete the directory.
Both are successfull `= 0` in my case.

Maybe that could bring up some light.

If the rmdir is successful but the directory is still there, the only idea I can think of is another process, which recreates that directory. - But this should be the same when manually deleting the directory...